# Hide a layer until a key is pressed as2

Tags: actionscript-2, layer

How would you hide a layer in as2 until a key is pressed by the user? I'm trying to create a titan fall like game where you can press E to jump to another layer and out of the 'mech' layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `hide` a layer with ActionScript. You must put all your objects in a `MovieClip`, and do like that:

```
var keyListener:Object = new Object();

keyListener.onKeyDown = function():Void {
    if (Key.getCode() == 69) myMovieClip._visible = false;
}
Key.addListener(keyListener);
```